# Where should I store data for a .NET Core Global Tool?

Tags: command-line, .net-core, dotnet-tool

I've recently started work on a [.NET Core Global Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools) and I have the need to store some user context data, similar to how `kubectl config set-context` works and affects other kubectl commands. Is there a standard pattern for this with .NET Core Global Tools? Or should this just be written to LocalSettings or similar?

Comment: I don't know what the standard pattern is, but I tend to use the home directory for the currently logged in user and use a .folder (i.e. `/home/username/.my-app-name` on a Unix-like). You could always use AppData/Local on Windows if you'd like